# Need help on a formula to leave cell blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am looking for help on a formula. I have the following formula for calculating the days that a task has been open. It works great as long as there is a date when it was opened. The problem I am having is if there is no date in the opened date column, it spits out 42795 in the cell I want blank.

Here is the formula: =IF(L19="",TODAY()-D19,L19-D19)

D19 is the Opened Date cell. L19 is the Closed Date cell. When the D19 cell is blank, I want the cell with this formula to be blank until a date is entered in D19.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap another IF:

```
=IF(D19 = "","",IF(L19="",TODAY()-D19,L19-D19))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't figure out how to wrap the other IF statement. Thank you very much for your help. It works perfect.

Comment: @John please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done, I am new and didn't know about that, sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: Scott, I have a similar issue to the one above. I tried to take your formula and tweak if for a countdown using the following formula: =J18-TODAY() I cannot figure out how to get it to show a blank if J18 is blank. I want to use this formula so it will show a negative if it is past the date in J18.

Comment: @John this is a new question and it deserves it own post, You can link back here to help explain.

Comment: Ok. I will create a new post.

Answer (score 0):

This does not create a blank cell in the adjacent cell. ="" or "" is not a blank cell. Use ISBLANK to confirm that your result is not a blank cell. When
=IF(D19 = "","",IF(L19="",TODAY()-D19,L19-D19))="",
=ISBLANK(IF(D19 = "","",IF(L19="",TODAY()-D19,L19-D19))) results in False.