# Need help on a formula to leave cell blank part 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a similar issue to the one in this previous post: [Need help on a formula to leave cell blank](https://superuser.com/questions/1184071/need-help-on-a-formula-to-leave-cell-blank)

I tried to take the formula and tweak if for a countdown using the following formula:
`=J18-TODAY()`

I cannot figure out how to get it to show a blank if `J18` **is blank**. I want to use this formula so it will show a negative if it is past the date in J18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same use of [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function. The exception is I use the [`ISBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) function to check if a cell is blank.

> IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)

The following formula checks if `J18` blank. If it returns true, then it does nothing (`""`) which leaves the cell blank. If it returns false, then it runs the formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY())
```

***NOTE: The question was focused on leaving the cell blank, so I did not test your formula.***

Comment: How would I include another IF statement to make it stop counting if there is a date in cell L18?

Comment: Create a new question for it and explain